# Ios text chat between devices on same wifi network

Tags: ios, wifip2p

I am start a work on new project and project requirement is text chat on same wifi network , Means two and three devices connected with same network one is host and another is user and user can text chat to host . I have try with alljoyn framework but is send group message and i cant able to find how to chat single user to host . 
Please help me . 
please share your valuable knowledge . 
Please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try Multipeer Connectivity FrameWork. It fits in ur scenerio. It is a framework introduced in iOS 7 and it totally rules. It Woks on Wifi as well as Bluetooth.

Check this link for a start. I found it very useful. (**Objective C**)

http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/

There is also Part 2 for this sample in the link.

Check this link too. (**SWIFT**)

http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/

There is also Part 2 for this sample in the link.

Comment: in objective c multipeet code is based on bluetooth but i have need on wifi network text chat

Comment: Download and check the sample app with wifi for objective C.